# Why showing and hiding view from viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, viewwillappear

I recently converted an app from modal `viewControllers` to `TabBarController` and there is some code that used to work fine before the conversion but now I'm having a hard time making it work in the TabBar app.

What I want to do is update the `UI`in a tab based on user setting stored in `UserDefaults`, these settings happen in the `Settings` tab (ViewController) and I want to update the UI in a different tab based on the settings that were set by the user. Before the conversion the code was in the `ViewDidLoad` and it was working fine but now with `TabBar` there is no `ViewDidLoad` I'm using viewWillAppear, to update as soon as the tab is activated but isn't working.

Here is the code...

```
class UserInputViewController: UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // customizeApp() // everything works if called from here
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        customizeApp() // Doesn't work
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // customizeApp() // Doesn't work
    }

     func customizeApp(){

        if isView1(){
            view1.isHidden = false
        }else{
            view1.isHidden = true
        }

        if isButton1(){
            button1.isHidden = false
        }else{
            button1.isHidden = true
        }

        if isTextField1(){
            textField1.isHidden = false
        }else{
            textField1.isHidden = true
        }

        if isTextField2(){
            textField2.isHidden = false
        }else{
            textField2.isHidden = true
        }

        /// Adjust Screen based on settings
        if textField1.isHidden && textField2.isHidden{
            constraintMainButton.constant = 7
            return
        }
        if textField1.isHidden {
            constraintMainButton.constant = 45
        }
        if textField2.isHidden {
            constraintMainButton.constant = 45
        }
    }

    func isView1()->Bool{// read UserDefaults}
    func isButton1()->Bool{// read UserDefaults}
    func isTextField1()->Bool{// read UserDefaults}
    func isTextField2()->Bool{// read UserDefaults}
}
```

I also tried `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but it didn't work either.

#### Any idea what could be wrong?

FYI - All values come as expected from `UserDefaults`.

### EDIT:

My Issue was that I was repositioning my views but I wasn't repositioning them back to their original position. I know it sounds silly but I was tricked by the fact that the exact same code was working fine when I was calling `customizeApp()` from `ViewDidLoad` before changing to `UITabBar`. I ended up calling `customizeApp()` from `viewDidAppear()` method.

```
 class UserInputViewController: UIViewController{

    /// ... Code

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        customizeApp()
    }

     func customizeApp(){

        /// ... Code

        /// Adjust Screen based on settings
        if textField1.isHidden && textField2.isHidden{
            constraintMainButton.constant = 7
            return
        }
        if textField1.isHidden {
            constraintMainButton.constant = 45
            return // added
        }
        if textField2.isHidden {
            constraintMainButton.constant = 45
            return // added
        }

        constraintMainButton.constant = 83 // added: Original Position
    }
    /// .... Code
}
```

Thanks

Comment: **Always** call super in `viewWillAppear` and others. Otherwise you're breaking everything.

Comment: Where do `view1`, `button1`, ... come from ?

Comment: Calling `super` seem to fix the issue. view1 and button1 are outlets. FYI - This is not production code, just enough to address the issue.

Comment: Ok. FYI, anything that starts with viewWill/viewDid, you must call super.

Comment: As a general rule, when overriding UIKit classes, call super unless the doc specifically says not to.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I just went with whatever XCode auto-completed.

Comment: As @deadbeef pointed out, you should add: `super.viewWillAppear(animated)` and `super.viewDidAppear(animated)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that "it doesn't work" is really un-helpful. You need to describe what your code does or doesn't do, in detail, if you want help.

There are several things wrong with your code.

In `viewDidLoad()`, `viewWillAppear(_:)`, and `viewWillDisappear(_:)`you must always call super.

Updating the constant on a constraint doesn't do anything until next time the view's layout is updated.

When you change your layout constraints in `viewDidLoad()`, it takes place before the layout has been finalized, so the changes are applied in the next layout pass.

If you want to make changes to constraints, you need to call `layoutIfNeeded()`. Try adding this to your `customizeApp()` function:

```
func customizeApp() {
  defer {
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, turned out that my problem was that I was repositioning my views but I wasn't repositioning them back to its original position. I know it sounds silly but I was tricked by the fact that the exact same code was working fine when I was calling `customizeApp()` from `ViewDidLoad` but thanks to your explanation I was able to find the problem. FYI - I didn't need to call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` I just called  `customizeApp()` from `viewDidAppear` and repositioned my views to their original position by adjusting their constraints. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/DefiningYourSubclass.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW1)

As @deadbeef says call super in viewWillAppear and others.

**Process of loading and displaying your view controller’s views**

Storyboards make the process of loading and displaying your view controller’s views very simple. UIKit automatically loads views from your storyboard file when they are needed. As part of the loading process, UIKit performs the following sequence of tasks:

1. Instantiates views using the information in your storyboard file.
2. Connects all outlets and actions.
3. Assigns the root view to the view controller’s view property.
4. Calls the view controller’s awakeFromNib method.

   When this method is called, the view controller’s trait collection is     empty and views may not be in their final positions.
5. Calls the view controller’s viewDidLoad method.

> Use **viewDidLoad** method to add or remove views, modify layout constraints,
> and load data for your views. Usually override this method to perform additional initialization on views that were loaded from nib files.

Before displaying a view controller’s views onscreen, UIKit gives you some additional chances to prepare those views before and after they are onscreen. Specifically, UIKit performs the following sequence of tasks:

1. Calls the view controller’s viewWillAppear: method to let it know
   that its views are about to appear onscreen.
2. Updates the layout of the views.
3. Displays the views onscreen.
4. Calls the viewDidAppear: method when the views are onscreen.

When you add, remove, or modify the size or position of views, remember to add and remove any constraints that apply to those views. Making layout-related changes to your view hierarchy causes UIKit to mark the layout as dirty. During the next update cycle, the layout engine computes the size and position of views using the current layout constraints and applies those changes to the view hierarchy.